# Formatting of full address using c# code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have written following lines of code for formatting of address

```
         string Address1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine1"].ToString();
            string Address2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine2"].ToString();
            string Address1C;
            string Address2C;

            if (Address1 != "")
                Address1C = Address1 + ", ";
            else
                Address1C = Address1;

            if (Address2 != "")
                Address2C = Address2 + ", ";
            else
                Address2C = Address2;



            lblAdderssX1.Text = Address1C + Address2C;

            string City = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressCity"].ToString();
            string CityC;
            if (City != "")
                CityC = City + ", ";
            else
                CityC = City;

            string Pin = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressPin"].ToString();

            string State = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JurisdictionX"].ToString();
            string StateC;

            if (State != "")
                StateC = State + ", ";
            else
                StateC = State;

          //  string CountryC = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CountryX"].ToString();

            lblAddressX2.Text = CityC + StateC + Pin;

         "<asp:Label ID="lblAdderssX1" CssClass="ProfileLabel" runat="server"> </asp:Label>
                                                                                   <asp:Label ID="lblAddressX2" CssClass="ProfileLabel" runat="server"> </asp:Label>"
```

Actually we want that the format should be like

"Physical Address1, Physical Address2, City, State, Pin"

if any of them is missing let's say  Physical Address2 then address should be

"Physical Address1, City, State, Pin"

and if City is missing in the table then it should be like

"Physical Address1, Physical Address2, State, Pin"

and if Physical Address2, City, State, Pin are missing then the address should be like

"Physical Address1" and currently the above is placing , in this case. I am not able to handle this. Please help !!!

Also if nothing is available then the text should come like "Not Available"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want to write it cleaner. Create `List<string>`

```
List<string> address = new List<string>();
address.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine1"].ToString());
address.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine2"].ToString());
address.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressCity"].ToString());
address.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JurisdictionX"].ToString());
address.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressPin"].ToString());

string list = string.Join(", ", address.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```

Comment: thanks for great answer but it is throwing error at list.toArray()

Comment: @Nida do you have using System.Linq; ?

Answer (score 0):

string Address1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine1"].ToString();

```
        string Address2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine2"].ToString();

        string City = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressCity"].ToString();
        string State = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JurisdictionX"].ToString();

        string Pin = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressPin"].ToString();

        string Address1C;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1))
            Address1C=Address1;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address2))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1C))
                Address1C = ", "+ Address2 ;
            else
            Address1C=Address2;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1C))
                Address1C = ", "+ City ;
            else
            Address1C=City;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(State))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1C))
                Address1C = ", "+ State ;
            else
            Address1C=State;
        }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pin))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1C))
                Address1C = ", "+ Pin ;
            else
            Address1C=Pin;
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1C))
            lblAdderssX1.Text = Address1C;
        else
        lblAdderssX1.Text = "Not Available";            


     //<asp:Label ID="lblAdderssX1" CssClass="ProfileLabel" runat="server"> </asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
string address = string.Empty;

if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine1"] != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine1"].ToString()))
    address += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine1"].ToString() + ", ";

if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine2"] != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine2"].ToString()))
    address += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressLine2"].ToString() + ", ";

if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressCity"] != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressCity"].ToString()))
    address += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressCity"].ToString() + ", ";

if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JurisdictionX"] != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JurisdictionX"].ToString()))
    address += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["JurisdictionX"].ToString() + ", ";

if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressPin"] != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressPin"].ToString()))
    address += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PhysicalAddressPin"].ToString() + ", ";

address = address.TrimEnd(", ");
```